# Can I use Javascript to Rotate and Crop a gallery of images prior to upload?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-4, croppie

I've been trying to use the file reader and croppie to allow users to edit their images locally (zoom / rotate / crop) prior to upload, but can't seem to get it to work correctly. I am suspecting this is a DOM issue because of the modal, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to make it work!

```js
FileReader () stuff
//
//
//create elements for image, edit and delete buttons, then appending to parent div
//
//

//place the new image and button into the new div
newdiv.appendChild(newimage);
newdiv.appendChild(newedit);
newdiv.appendChild(newdelete);

//place the new div into the results div
output.appendChild(newdiv);

//add event listeners to dynamically created buttons
newdelete.addEventListener('click', delImage, false);
newedit.addEventListener('click', showModal, false);

.
.
.

function showModal(){
    var edit_id = this.getAttribute("dataset-editid");
    var image_id = document.getElementById('img-'+edit_id);
    var thisImage = image_id.src;
    $('#'+edit_id).click(function(){
        $("#cropImagePop").modal();
    });
    console.log(edit_id);
    console.log('image source: ' + image_id);
    var themodal = document.getElementById('cropImagePop');
    var theimage = document.getElementById('cropimage');
    var instance = new Croppie(theimage, {
        viewport: { width: 300, height: 300 },
        boundary: { width: 900, height: 600 },
        showZoomer: true,
        enableResize: true,
        url: thisImage
    });

}
```

When I click the dynamic 'edit' button for any given picture the modal opens, but the photo is really large (not staying within the modal), and there is not a bounding box to crop to..

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/noz2eb3y/

*Also - I am by no means married to Croppie - if someone has a great (working!) javascript library they know of which can zoom/rotate/crop images - I'm all ears!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question: Yes it is possible.

The issue with the modal window is because you forgot to add the croppie css reference.

I fixed that in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wyqozf8t/) and also added a function to the crop button, to update the source element.

See the following example:

```
$('#cropImageBtn').click(function(){
  instance.result('base64').then(function(base64) {
    image_id.src = base64;
    cleanModal();
  });
});
$('#closeImageBtn').click(function(){
    cleanModal();
});
function cleanModal()
{
  instance.destroy();
  $("#cropImagePop").modal("hide");
}
```

Next steps you need to take if you want to upload the image(s).

1. Take a look at [jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
2. Post the base64 encoded data to your server
3. Decode the base64 encoded data
4. Save the image file

I'd also recommend to improve your code (it's a bit mixed up).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I realize my code isn't that great, and I'll work on it - but your fixes and explanation are more than enough to get me on my way. I really appreciate it. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help ;)